# Passport-local never authenticating with correct credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport.js, passport-local

I'm trying to use `passport-local` to bake some authentication and password hashing into a small web app. I believe I've set it up correctly, however I am sent through the failure redirect to login again, even though the credentials are 110% correct.

The passport documentation is extremely light on debugging errors, can anyone share shed some light on the possible cause of this failure redirect, or offer a solution to continue debugging?

**Passport Config**

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password'
},
  function(username, password, cb) {
     UserSchema.findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return cb(err); }
      if (!user) { return cb(null, false); }
      if (user.password != password) { return cb(null, false); }
      return cb(null, user);
    });
  }));
```

**Login Route**

```
router.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

**Schema and findByUsername function**

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema ({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    index: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    index: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    index: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    index: true
  },
  homeAirport: {
    type: String,
    index: true
  }
})

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose)

// Adding this function to find by username
exports.findByUsername = function(username, cb) {
  process.nextTick(function() {
    for (var i = 0, len = records.length; i < len; i++) {
      var record = records[i];
      if (record.username === username) {
        return cb(null, record);
      }
    }
    return cb(null, null);
  });
}

// Export it to the app
module.exports = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema)
```

Comment: As a debug step, replace your user returning function with one that returns a literal user object.

Comment: Also, I'm kind of a noob at this, but in a little project I tried, I used passportLocalMongoose, which adds username, password, salt, etc to my user model as well as methods found here https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose#api-documentation

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the Passport docs:

> A redirect is commonly issued after authenticating a request.

My guess is that because you only have a `{failureRedirect: '/login' }`
you are always redirected there. Try adding this:

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

So in this case you have a `successRedirect` and a `failureRedirect`

Or you could also just remove the redirect after authenticating, and instead redirect the user like this:

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    console.log('Successfully logged in');
    res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
  });
```

Let me know if this works